# How connect to Sybase custdb.db using SwisSQL?

Tags: oracle, database-migration, sqlanywhere, swissql

How connect to Sybase custdb.db using SwisSQL?
I work with standart Sybase sample.

I input appropriate command line:

```
"mlsrv12.exe -vcrs -zu+
   -c "dsn=SQL Anywhere 12 CustDB;uid=ml_server;pwd=sql"
   -x http(port=80)"
```

Database work fine - I test it from InteractiveSQL and from Android - client. 
When I try to migrate from this database to Oracle I have trouble.

```
Host name: 127.0.0.1
Port number: 80
User name: ml_server
Password: sql
Service ID (SID): custdb
Shema(optional): empty
```

What I am doing wrong?

Any help appreciated!